# Stored procedure with default NULL parameter to return cubed results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is how the stored procedure would be structured:

```
[dbo].[getSp] (
  @Color varchar(10) = Null,
  @Finish varchar(10) = Null,
  @Height varchar(10) = Null,
  @Type varchar(10) = Null,
  @Trim varchar(10) = Null,
  @Width varchar(10) = Null
)
```

This is how the data looks before searched..This data is incomplete, but as an example to get an idea. Every combination would be in here..

```
Color  |  Finish  |  Height  |   Type    |  Trim  |  Width  |
 Blue  |  Shiny   |   Tall   |  Toaster  | Normal |   3.5   |
(NULL) |  (NULL)  |  (NULL)  |  Toaster  | (NULL) |   3.5   |
(NULL) |  (NULL)  |   Tall   |  Toaster  |  Deco  |    4    |
(NULL) |  Shiny   |   Tall   |  Toaster  |  Deco  |    4    |
 Blue  |  Shiny   |  (NULL)  |  Toaster  |  Deco  |    4    |
(NULL) |  Shiny   |   Tall   |  Toaster  |  Deco  |    4    |
(NULL) |  Satin   |   Tall   |  Toaster  |  Deco  |    4    |
  Red  |  (NULL)  |   Tall   |  Toaster  |  Deco  |    4    |
```

The SELECT statement would have `Type` as the primary lookup field, so it would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Type = @Type And
(

..... Confused about this part, 

)
```

But basically, I would like to run a stored procedure to only include those combinations, which are rows found in the table when called with only a part of the params, like this:

```
[getSp] 
@Color='Blue',
@Finish='Shiny',
@Type='toaster'
```

And the sp would ultimately return this (every combination)..

```
1. Blue Shiny Tall Toaster
2. Blue Shiny Toaster
3. Blue Tall Toaster
4. Blue Toaster
5. Tall Toaster
6. Shiny Toaster
7. Shiny Tall Toaster
```

So I am confused about how to structure the `Where` statement in the stored procedure to return every combination for ONLY those which you include in the stored procedure params, but the remaining params (like `Width` and `Trim` would be left out of the results and searching, would and when passed as `NULL` by default.

I've tried this without any luck...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 
Type = @Type AND
(
COLOR = COALESCE(@Color,COLOR) AND...
... for each other param
)
```

I've tried this without any luck...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 
Type = @Type AND
(
(Color = @Color OR COALESCE(@Color,COLOR) IS NULL) OR...
... for each other param
)
```

I've tried building the sql statement, but have failed as well.. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should meet your needs, if you provide a param then it uses it to filter otherwise it won't:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
WHERE (@Color IS NULL OR Color = @Color)
AND (@Finish IS NULL OR Finish = @Finish)
AND (@Height IS NULL OR Height = @Height)
AND (@Type IS NULL OR Type = @Type)
AND (@Trim IS NULL OR Trim = @Trim)
AND (@Width IS NULL OR Width = @Width)
```

Comment: Doesn't return the results i'm looking for..  Actually it only returns the rows like #1, all other levels doesn't return.